# How to Copy Image File from Gallery to another folder without changing its modified date programmatically?

Tags: android, image, move, copy-paste, last-modified

```
 private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile){
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile)) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath(), fos);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Tag",e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Tag", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I tried above code copy paste working but modified date is also changed and I don't want to change modified date.

Comment: What has this to do with a Gallery app? Please provide values for sourceFile.getAbsolutePath() and destFile.getAbsolutePath(). Put them at the beginning of your post. You should have told of course how you called your function.

Comment: Which modified time does it get now? You forgot to tell that too.

Comment: I tried the same only word gallery is used nothing do with gallery.

Comment: like i try to copy image of before five days then in destination folder modified date will be the day of copy not before five days.

Comment: Yes the modified date is different. But which date does it get then? What is the value? Thats what i asked. Please tell.

Comment: I get current date in result.

Comment: You did not show how you did the copy as code for `Files.copy(sourceFile.toPath()...` fails. So we do not know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help but now my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Date date = new Date(files.get(i).lastModified());

new File(outputPath + "/" + inputFile).setLastModified(newDate.getTime());
```

first get last modified date before copy and after paste apply that last modified date to new file